# Google analytics for web widget

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have developed a web widget which is a bootstrap modal.This can be implement any HTML website.Widget has basically youtube videos. I need to track user interactions on this widget. How can I do it with google analytics? or is there any better way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to install your Analytics tracking code (and eventual events) in the web app as you would in a website.

Comment: can you please share a tutorial link or something like that?

Comment: You can find all information in official docs, i.e. (Adding analytics.js to Your Site):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: Thank you @MichelePisani